# How do I get rid of group argument must be None for now error in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run the following code but I keep getting an error.

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
from random import randint 

mouse = Controller()


numbers = [0.08, 0.05, 0.012, 0.07, 0.06, 0.012, 0.05, 0.014, 0.02]




delay = numbers[randint(0,8)]
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='F')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()



def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Error:

```
file "C:\Users\jpbas\OneDrive\Desktop\autoclicker.py", line 47, in <module>
    click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
>>>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your `__init__` method is spelled correctly? Because the error you describe is what I'd expect if Python isn't seeing that method at all. It doesn't make any sense if the method exists properly.

Comment: @Blcknght it turns out that you were right, the version i had in the idle it was spelled init instead of __init__ thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) documentation  for an explanation on the `group` argument and why it has to be `None`.

According to that doc, the error you are getting seems to come from the

`super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()`

line since this is the place where you initialize a `threading.Thread` instance.
Try putting the keyword argument `group=None` there (even though that is the default value for that argument).

On a side note, running your code doesn't give me any errors. Is there anything else, maybe in the environment that can affect this?